# get classname jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<div class="static dynamic1 dynamic2 prop">Hello SO</div>
```

I need to get `dynamic1` and `dynamic2` (get classname that which begins with `dynamic`)

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - JQuery has documented nearly everything, please consult that first.

Comment: @undefined i do not want to select the DOM ,instead of that i need to get its classname as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cls = $('div')[0].className.split(' ');
var dynamics = $.grep(cls, function(v) {
    return v.indexOf('dynamic') > -1
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C88uF/

`dynamics` variable is an array, if you want to convert it to a string, you can use `join` method:

```
dynamics.join(' ')
```

Comment: Be aware of `$('div')[0]`, ID should be used in case of web page.

Comment: @Dev why should i need to use ID ? there are many elements with same attr.

Comment: Oh, if its multiple elements then a class is fine, you just need one for defining selector.

Answer (score -1):

Add ID mydiv to the element and use following:

```
var str = $('#mydiv').attr('class');

str = str.split(' ');

var res = new Array();
for(key in str){
    if(str[key].indexOf('dynamic') >= 0)
        res.push(str[key]);
}

alert(res);
```